# org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver: HiveBaseResultSet has not implemented absolute()?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, jdbc, hive, thrift

I just started using the driver `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` (Version 
 1.2.1 for spark2) with a Spark Thrift Server (STS) (reference [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/content/spark-sql-thrift-server.html))

`java.sql.ResultSet` defines the method `absolute()` (JavaDoc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html?is-external=true))

but `HiveBaseResultSet` seems to have chosen not to implement the method (source code [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/trunk/jdbc/src/java/org/apache/hive/jdbc/HiveBaseResultSet.java))

So now my application (built on top of `SmartGWT`) was doing a simple operation and I got the following error message:

```
=== 2017-05-13 18:06:16,980 [3-47] WARN  RequestContext - dsRequest.execute() failed:
java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveBaseResultSet.absolute(HiveBaseResultSet.java:70)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.absolute(DelegatingResultSet.java:373)
        at com.isomorphic.sql.SQLDataSource.executeWindowedSelect(SQLDataSource.java:2970)
        at com.isomorphic.sql.SQLDataSource.SQLExecute(SQLDataSource.java:2024)
```

What is the reason that the driver chose not to implement `absolute()`?

Are there any workaround for the limitation?

Comment: What is your question? I hope you are aware that the `absolute(int)` method is 1) optional, 2) expected to throw an `SQLException` for a forward only result set (the default).

Comment: @Mark -- Okay.  Thanks! Now I understand.

Comment: Now I changed my application to avoid calling `absolute()` and I got pass that error.  Now I saw another error: `java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.commit(HiveConnection.java:742)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334)
        at com.isomorphic.sql.SQLTransaction.commitTransaction(SQLTransaction.java:307)
`.  So now the problem shifted to `commit()`  How can I work around this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the hint from Mark Rotteveel.  Now I understand better and let me post an answer to my own question.

**Implementation of absolute() is optional**

As specified by the Interface of `ResultSet#absolute()` ([link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#absolute(int))), the implementation for `absolute()` is optional -- especially when the result set type is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`.

**Workaround**

In my case, the result set comes from a Spark Thrift Server (STS) so I guess it is indeed forward-only.  So the question became how to instruct my application to NOT making a call to `absolute()`, which is basically for cursor movement.

***SmartGWT-specific answer***

For `SmartGWT`, this is controlled by a property called `sqlPaging`, which we can specified for an `OperationBinding`.  The right value to use seems to be `dropAtServer` (more reference [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-release/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/types/SQLPagingStrategy.html)).  So I set my SmartGWT DataSource XML file to something like this

```
<operationBindings>
    <operationBinding   operationType="fetch"  progressiveLoading="false"
                sqlPaging="dropAtServer" 
        >
```

After that I saw another error, which is now related to `HiveConnection#commit()`:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.commit(HiveConnection.java:742)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.commit(DelegatingConnection.java:334)
    at com.isomorphic.sql.SQLTransaction.commitTransaction(SQLTransaction.java:307)
    at com.isomorphic.sql.SQLDataSource.commit(SQLDataSource.java:4673)
```

After more digging, I realized that the right property for SmartGWT to control the commit behavior is `autoJoinTransactions` and I should set it to false (more reference [here](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee-5.1/server/javadoc/com/isomorphic/rpc/RPCManager.html#setTransactionPolicy-int-)).  After these two changes, I could get may application to talk to STS via `jdbc.HiveDriver`

For anyone out there who are also trying this, here is my full settings for the driver in SmartGWT's `server.properties` (more reference [here](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/SqlSettings.html))

```
sql.defaultDatabase: perf2 # this name is picked by me, but it can be anyname

sql.perf2.driver.networkProtocol: tcp
sql.perf2.driver: org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver   # important
sql.perf2.database.type: generic                    # important
sql.perf2.autoJoinTransactions: false               # important
sql.perf2.interface.type: driverManager             # important
sql.perf2.driver.url: jdbc:hive2://host:port        # important -- pick your host:port
sql.perf2.driver.user: someuser                     # important -- pick your username
sql.perf2.interface.credentialsInURL: true
sql.perf2.driver.databaseName: someDb
sql.perf2.driver.context:
```